# turtlebot_simulator on hydro barely usable due to robot slipping

Tags: gazebo, simulation, roomba, turtlebot, turtlebot-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just tried out the turtlebot_simulator for hydro (everything installed from .debs) using a roomba base and the robot is moving pretty erratic. If a turn is commanded, the robot will keep rotating after 0 turn rate is commanded. It looks like this is a problem with friction parameters and I´m pretty sure this worked better last time I tried (more than a year ago). Any suggestions on how to improve the situation are appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191478/turtlebot_simulator-on-hydro-barely-usable-due-to-robot-slipping/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2014-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looked into this and it appears the friction parameters were way off. After changing them to be the same as on the Kobuki, things are working fine. See also [turtlebot_create pull request 20](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_create/pull/20).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0